# what is wrong with this async function in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, frontend, vuejs3

It's quite a simple concept error, but anyway I'm not being able to solve it, I'm making an axios.get() in a onMounted hook, inside the block of the onMounted everything is showing correct ⇾ an Array of three objects. But once I return it to the template and interpolate it to see the value is just an empty Array.
here's the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Events for good</h1>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    <EventCard v-for="event in events" :key="event.id" :event="event"/>
    {{ events }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted, reactive } from 'vue';

import { Event } from '@/types/event';

import EventCard from '@/components/EventCard.vue';

import axios from 'axios';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'EventList',
  components: {
    EventCard
  },
  setup() {

  let events = reactive<Event[]>([])

  onMounted( async() => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/events'); 
    console.log(response.data)
    events = response.data
    console.log(events)
  })
    return {
      events
    }
  }
  });
</script>
```

And here's the log and interpolation image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`events` is overwritten with `response.data`, which effectively removes the original `reactive()` instance from the component's context:

```js
let events = reactive<Event[]>([])

onMounted(async () => {
  ⋮
  events = response.data // ❌ `events` is now the same as `response.data`,
                         // and the original value is gone!
})
```

***Note:** Using `const` here usually prevents these mistakes:*

```js
const events = reactive<Event[]>([]) //  const prevents accidental overwrites like above
```

### Solution

One solution is to declare `events` as a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) instead of `reactive`:

```js
const events = ref<Event[]>([])

onMounted(async () => {
  ⋮
  events.value = response.data // ✅ `events.value` is now the same value as `response.data`
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-reactive-value-v2?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Object.assign` to mutate the reactive data:

```js
 Object.assign(events, response.data)
```

Or define a state using reactive and define `events` as field :

```js
let state = reactive({
  events:[]
})
...
state.events = response.data
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly if the new array is smaller than the original ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-reactive-value-v2-miqqv3?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)).